# Problem using Linq to Sql queries DataBinding to a WPF Combobox

Tags: wpf, linq-to-sql, data-binding, combobox

I have the following WPF markup

```
<ComboBox x:Name="realmComboBox" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
          SelectedValuePath="Name" 
          Width="120" />
```

I've found numerous examples on the web that say one of the following should work

```
realmComboBox.ItemsSource = from realm in _db.Realms select realm;

realmComboBox.ItemsSource = (from realm in _db.Realms select realm).ToList();
```

but all I get is a blank drop down. Not even the ToString problem that I'm told happens if you don't set DisplayMemberPath. The only thing I have found that works is the following

```
realmComboBox.ItemsSource = from realm in _db.Realms 
                            select new { 
                                Name = realm.Name
                            };
```

But this feels like a total waste of resources since I already have the Realm object in memory and it clearly has a Name property. What am I missing?

Comment: Is `Realm.Name` a public property? If not that might be a problem...

Comment: Oh yeh! I was thinking about what the answer to this one would be, of course. Also, checking the Output Window in Visual Studio when debugging will help you identify binding errors. Some are a little cryptic, and others are of little help, but the error in this case would have mentioned something like `unable to find public property 'Name' on object 'Realm'` or something to that effect.

Comment: The Name property is public. When I run under the debugger there is no output in the Immediate Window. The object does use the [Table] attribute and the property has the [Column] attribute could those be interfering some how?

Comment: @H.B. should be the one to put this in as an answer to get the points. But the solution for this will be to change the `public string Name` to `public string Name { get; set; }` -- Edit: You've edited your comment; What you had before showed that `Name` was a field, and not a property.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment, this is a public [field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx):

```
public string Name;
```

And this is a public [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx):

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Since it works with the anonymous type which only uses properties i would assume your data only has public fields.

Also: the immediate-window is not the output-window, you may need to show it via `View > Output`.

Comment: It is possible to configure Visual Studio to redirect debug messages to the immediate window. http://www.professionalvisualstudio.com/blog/2008/07/24/debugging-tip-of-the-week-1-the-immediate-window/

Comment: I can see the output window when I build but as soon as I run in the debugger, Visual Studio closes it and the View | Output menu item is not available.